# How to optimize this query with joins, limits and min over 3 tables with lots of data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to optimize a query that is easy to explain, but hard to write. I have a website that allows users to upload images to folders and publish these folders on a certain date.

I want to display images from the latest folders, the image with the smaller filename (i.e. 0.jpg, 1.jpg I'd pick 0.jpg), from only published image folders.

The database structure is as follows (I've ommited non-relevant columns for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE image (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "imageFileId" integer REFERENCES image_file(id),
    "imageFolderId" integer REFERENCES image_folder(id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_d6db1ab4ee9ad9dbe86c64e4cc3" ON image(id int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX "IDX_IMAGE_IMAGE_FOLDER" ON image("imageFolderId" int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX "IDX_IMAGE_IMAGE_FILE" ON image("imageFileId" int4_ops);


CREATE TABLE image_file (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    filename character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT 'file.jpg'::character varying,
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_a63c149156c13fef954c6f56398" ON image_file(id int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX "IDX_IMAGE_FILE_FILENAME" ON image_file(filename text_ops);

CREATE TABLE image_folder (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "publicationDate" timestamp without time zone,
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_7913e2df97a29ff24201598251e" ON image_folder(id int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX "IDX_IMAGE_FOLDER_PUBLICATION_DATE" ON image_folder("publicationDate" timestamp_ops);
```

We've come up with this query, which after setting `random_page_cost` to `1` did became faster, but it is still rather slow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON (image_folder."publicationDate", image."imageFolderId") image.*
FROM image
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT "imageFolderId", min(image_file.filename) AS "firstFileName"
    FROM image
    INNER JOIN image_file
        ON image_file.id = image."imageFileId"
    GROUP BY  image."imageFolderId" ) AS first_image_file
    ON first_image_file."imageFolderId" = image."imageFolderId"
INNER JOIN image_folder
    ON image_folder.id = image."imageFolderId"
INNER JOIN image_file
    ON image_file.id = image."imageFileId"
WHERE image_file.filename = first_image_file."firstFileName"
        AND image_folder."publicationDate" IS NOT NULL
        AND image_folder."publicationDate" <= now()

ORDER BY  image_folder."publicationDate" DESC,
        image."imageFolderId" DESC,
        image_file.filename ASC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

Is there anything I can do to optimize this query? I'm considering making the database simpler and getting rid of `image_file`, but as it is a very image-centered website, I may need some extra metadata on these files which is why it was designed like this.

UPDATE: This only started to get slow when I got ~500k records on each table. This will definitely increase in a short time and will probably get even slower.

UPDATE 2: Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=47064.65..47064.65 rows=1 width=53)
  ->  Unique  (cost=47064.65..47064.65 rows=1 width=53)
        ->  Sort  (cost=47064.65..47064.65 rows=1 width=53)
              Sort Key: image_folder."publicationDate" DESC, image."imageFolderId" DESC, image_file.filename
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=35419.77..47064.65 rows=1 width=53)
                    Join Filter: (image_1."imageFolderId" = image_folder.id)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=35419.71..47064.58 rows=1 width=49)
                          Join Filter: (image_1."imageFolderId" = image."imageFolderId")
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=35419.63..46000.90 rows=9454 width=21)
                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=35419.55..35447.66 rows=9371 width=40)
                                      Group Key: image_1."imageFolderId"
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=11870.20..34935.82 rows=483723 width=17)
                                            Hash Cond: (image_file_1.id = image_1."imageFileId")
                                            ->  Seq Scan on image_file image_file_1  (cost=0.00..21237.56 rows=502521 width=17)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=10177.17..10177.17 rows=483723 width=8)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on image image_1  (cost=0.00..10177.17 rows=483723 width=8)
                                ->  Index Scan using "IDX_IMAGE_FILE_FILENAME" on image_file  (cost=0.08..1.12 rows=1 width=17)
                                      Index Cond: ((filename)::text = (min((image_file_1.filename)::text)))
                          ->  Index Scan using "IDX_IMAGE_IMAGE_FILE" on image  (cost=0.08..0.11 rows=1 width=32)
                                Index Cond: ("imageFileId" = image_file.id)
                    ->  Index Scan using "PK_7913e2df97a29ff24201598251e" on image_folder  (cost=0.06..0.06 rows=1 width=12)
                          Index Cond: (id = image."imageFolderId")
                          Filter: (("publicationDate" IS NOT NULL) AND ("publicationDate" <= now()))
```

Comment: First of all I barely see any filtering condition. You are reading pretty much all rows from each table. Is it so?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get the latest image folders in this list so people can browse it using pagination.

Comment: From every folder, that has been published now or in the past show the image contained in the folder with the lexicographical smallest name -- is that, what you want? And if, can there be ties, i.e. two images with the same name in one folder? If, how should the right image be chosen?

Comment: @stickybit yes, that's what I want. I don't care which file gets picked if they are the same filename, either would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to push the `LIMIT` down, rewrite it to use the `row_number()` window function to get the lexicographical smallest file name per folder and simplify it here and there.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x."imageFileId",
       x."imageFolderId"
       FROM (SELECT im.id,
                    im."imageFileId",
                    im."imageFolderId",
                    imfo."publicationDate",
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY imfo.id
                                       ORDER BY imfi.filename DESC) rn
                    FROM (SELECT *
                                 FROM image_folder
                                 WHERE "publicationDate" <= now()
                                 ORDER BY "publicationDate" DESC
                                 LIMIT 40) imfo
                         INNER JOIN image im
                                    ON im."imageFolderId" = imfo.id
                         INNER JOIN image_file imfi
                                    ON imfi.id = im."imageFileId"
                    WHERE imfo."publicationDate" <= now()) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1
       ORDER BY x."publicationDate" DESC,
                x."imageFolderId" DESC;
```

Additionally try indexes `ON image ("imageFolderId", "imageFileId")` and `ON image_folder ("publicationDate" DESC)`. If you're on version >= 10 you might also experiment with hash indexes `ON image_file USING HASH (id)` and/or `ON image_folder USING HASH (id)`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I see:

- Your query barely has any filtering condition. You are theoretically reading most of the rows.
- Your query has a `LIMIT` clause that shows only 40 rows. This can be effective as a filtering condition only if the query can be "pipelined". It looks your query may be.
- Your query has a subquery in the form of a Table Expression that you join against. This subquery **has no filter condition**. Therefore it reads ALL rows from `image` and `image_file`. To me this sounds like the culprit.

Now, is there any chance you could "save" this subquery into a separate table and query against it instead? Maybe you could update it once an hour, and add the proper indexes on it. If this is a real possibility I think you will see real improvements in your query just by doing this.

You can use a [Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) instead of a table and "refresh" it once an hour or so, or after some special events you identify.

In any case, I would get the execution plan and add it to your question. That will give us a good understanding on what PostgreSQL's optimizer is doing. To get the execution plan prepend `explain` to your select, as in:

```
explain
SELECT DISTINCT
ON (image_folder."publicationDate", image."imageFolderId") image.*
FROM image
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added the query plan.

Comment: Yep, I see it. In the most inner elements of the plan you can see the high cost. For example a "Hash Join" that reads 483723 rows, and a "Seq Scan" that reads 502521 rows. Those ones correspond to the subquey and are the main culprit. In third place it's the "Sort Key" that adds cost, but I would tackle that one later.

Comment: To put it simple, you can't be matching half a million rows against another half a million rows on every query. Well... unless it's a nightly process that runs only once a day.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll try get ridding of the `min(filename)` and filter `image` using a `boolean` filter to be created, filtering by this. I'll add as an answer if it works. This `min(filename)` is to use as a cover, which could be set elsewhere (even on `image_folder`)